# Doctrine entity callback not called

Tags: php, database, events, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have added `@ORM\Entity` and `@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks` annotations in my entity class and later in the entity class I have added the callback method with the right annotation (as following):

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
protected function PreUpdateHandler()
{
    echo '*********** PRE UPDATE *************';
    var_dump('*********** PRE UPDATE *************');
    return $this;
}
```

But the `PreUpdateHandler` is not getting called upon any DB manipulation (insert, update or delete). Any idea what am I missing?

BTW: Where can I see the list of all available event annotations (likes of @ORM\PreUpdate and @ORM\PrePersist)?

**IMPORTANT!!!**
My entity class is inherited from a base Entity class which is located in another directory (and namespace). I have added the `HasLifecycleCallbacks` annotation in the metadata of the base class as well. Does this matter for the callbacks to trigger?

Comment: How did you know it's not called?

Comment: nothing on the console... no var_dump, no echo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO the thing is that I am using the yml file as well as the entity class and it seems as if the annotations doesn't work in parallel to the yml file. I removed the annotations and added the callbacks in the yml file and its working.

Answer (score 3):

Your lifecycle callback method PreUpdateHandler is not invoked because the visibility of method is protected and hence not accessible by the ORM. Change the visibility to public and try.

Comment: Changed! but still no luck :(

Comment: Check with a die or some logging inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and check your result

```
$em->persist($object);
$object->PreUpdateHandler()
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Its called this way, but not called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your annotation callback

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
```

To

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
```

Comment: see my response above. BTW , I tried ur suggestion but still that didnt work.